# Robot Framework API - how to get suite and its test cases results

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I have a test suite directory which contains test suite files with one or more test cases. Let's say it looks like this:

```
TestSuite
  Test-1
    Step 1
    Step 2
  Test-2
    Step 1
  Test-3
    Step 1
    Step 2
    Step 3
```

I would like to parse output.xml to get results like this:

```
Test-1 | PASS
Test-1 | Step 1 | PASS
Test-1 | Step 2 | PASS
Test-2 | PASS
Test-2 | Step 1 | PASS
Test-3 | PASS
Test-3 | Step 1 | PASS
Test-3 | Step 2 | PASS
Test-3 | Step 3 | PASS
```

So far I have managed to get only suite files names and results using this code:

```py
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, SuiteVisitor

class PrintSuiteInfo(SuiteVisitor):

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        print('{} | {}'.format(suite.name, suite.status))

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.suite.suites.visit(PrintSuiteInfo())
```

which gives this output:

```
Test-1 | PASS
Test-2 | PASS
Test-3 | PASS
```

I can get test case names and results with this code:

```py
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor

class PrintTestInfo(ResultVisitor):

    def visit_test(self, test):
        print('{} | {}'.format(test.name, test.status))

result = ExecutionResult('output.xml')
result.visit(PrintTestInfo())
```

but the output is:

```
Step 1 | PASS
Step 2 | PASS
Step 1 | PASS
Step 1 | PASS
Step 2 | PASS
Step 3 | PASS
```

so there is no relation to suite files which I need to update results in Jira.

The only thing that came to my mind is to include the suite file name in each test case name but I would like to learn more about robot.api. I looked into [the documentation](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io) many times but it is not clear enough for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues helped me with solving this. What I was missing was:

```
test.parent
```

or one that I figured out myself:

```
test.longname
```

which gives output like this:

```
TestSuite.Test-1.Step 1
TestSuite.Test-1.Step 2
...
```

It is documented [here](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.model.html?highlight=testcase%20object#robot.model.testcase.TestCase).